# INSERT table row to another table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, output

I have two identical tables in my database. I'm trying to ask the user the package number, then when the user clicks a button, it will copy the row matching the user input to another table.

My tables are:

1. `awb` - where the original data is.
2. `temp` - table to insert the data into.

Here's my code:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbname = "outbound";
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
$packNO = $_GET['packNO'];
    // Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$packNO = mysql_real_escape_string($packNO);
    //build query
$query_add="INSERT INTO temp FROM awb WHERE packNO = '$packNO'";

@mysql_query($query_add);

$query = "SELECT * FROM temp";

$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

The code that follows outputs the content of the `temp` table. But when I print it, I get nothing.

Why is the `temp` table empty when I print its values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$query_add="INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM awb WHERE packNO = '$packNO'";
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: It did insert. Thank you. :D but it still doesn't output what's inside the temp table.  I have this warning - mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\myajax.php on line 65. I think I'll make another query that has only select statement. thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar query, but not using `*`

```
$query_add="INSERT INTO temp (packNO, name)  
SELECT packNO, name
FROM `awb`
WHERE `packNO` = '$packNO'";
```